# SCons for Java; Is there an analog for env.Program()?

Tags: java, scons

I need to create an executable file, run, that will call # java for my classes

I am compiling my java project with SCons:

```
libFiles = "lib/myLibs.jar"

# Build the environment
env = Environment(JAVACLASSPATH = libFiles, JAVASOURCEPATH = '.')
env.Java(target = 'classes', source = 'src')
```

All of the classes are stored in folder classes/ and all the source files are in /src .  To run the program, I have to

```
# cd classes/
# java -cp . myProg
```

Is there a way to have SCons create an executable in the root directory so it can call java by itself? I looked at an existing project that used env.Program() but that was only for C++.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: is there a special reason you are using SCons to build a Java project? The de-facto standard build tools for Java are Apache Ant and Apache Maven. http://ant.apache.org http://maven.apache.org

Comment: unfortunately, the main project is in C++ and this module is written in Java for GUI related issues.  

The only reason why I kept using SCons so the top level SCons directory can build all of the files including the Java module.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Jar](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#b-Jar) builder. The following SCons example does what you want.

```
jar = java_env = Jar(target='Observer',
                     source=['Observer.java',
                             'Manifest.txt'])
```

Note that if you want the Manifest.txt file to work as well it must have the following first line:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

You should only use the [Java](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#b-Java) builder if you want to generate the .class files.